# What is the difference between 'what you waiting for' and 'what are you waiting for'?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

What is the difference between

> What you waiting for?

and

> What are you waiting for?

Comment: I believe that the first one is just a contracted form of the second. People usually use this when in a hurry. This also may depict dialect variation from zone to zone. Some people may also say it is a poor English usage.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that "What you waiting for?" is not standard English. It may be dialect speech. We ask questions about someone's actions using a form of the verb 'to be', e.g. What **are** you waiting for? What **is** he doing? Where **are** you going? When **will** she come? Why **did** he do that? Who **is** that man?